# statsmodel.SARIMAX .forecast() method do not execute

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use SARIMAX model for TS forecasting. However, I got some kind of error i dont know how to handle. My code is simple:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

fit = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train).fit()
sarima = fit.forecast()
```

train data looks like

```
            y
ds  
2015-01-07  1
2015-01-14  64
2015-01-21  16
2015-01-28  50
2015-02-04  7
```

I got the error

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/datetools.py in 
_date_from_idx(d1, idx, freq)
     84     offset. For now, this needs to be taken care of before you get 
     here.
     85     """
---> 86     return _maybe_convert_period(d1) + int(idx) * 
     _freq_to_pandas[freq]
     87 
     88 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your desired output, the model summary, a plot, or just y hat?

Comment: @W.Dodge i just want forecast for 50 days, thats yhat

Comment: Did you check that all your data is valid? Maybe some of the dates or y values are None. Are you getting this error when fitting or at prediction?

Answer (score 0):

[SARIMA](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html#statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX) is a fairly complex moving average predictive model with many parameters and nuances. You will need to research the details of this approach extensively to be sure that you are utilizing this appropriately. For the sake of simply implementing the model to obtain a result, the following example should help:

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

data = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=30))
steps_to_predict = 5

model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog=data,order=(2,0,0),enforce_stationarity=False)
sarima = model.fit()
print(sarima.summary())

# plot   
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20,10))
ax.set_xlim(0,40)
ax.plot(train, "ro-", linewidth=2, markersize=12)
ax.plot(list(range(30,35)), sarima.forecast(steps_to_predict), "bo-", linewidth=2, markersize=12)
```

**Output:**

[image]

*** Note that the observed data is red and the predicted steps are blue.